# How to get the projection of ui.Map in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine

I know it's 3857, but I would really like to not hard-code it, only so that the script fails later when the GEE team decides to switch.
What I tried is to get the projection from a displayed image of a layer:

```
Map.layers().get(0).getEeObject().projection()
```

But it just returns 4326, which is obviously not the map's, nor the displayed layer's projection. It's actually not even the image's projection, but that's another story.

Any other suggestions?